# Valgrind reports leaked memory on OS X 10.8.1

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using Valgrind version 3.8.0 on OS X 10.8.1, Mountain Lion.  Regarding compatibility with 10.8.1, [Valgrind's site](http://valgrind.org/downloads/) says (italics mine):

> *Valgrind 3.8.0 works on* {x86,amd64}-darwin (Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7, with limited support for 10.8).

I know, then, that there is only "limited support" for 10.8.1.  Nonetheless, [this bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=304259) says (italics mine):

> This *(the latest 3.8.0 release)* makes *Valgrind*
>   compile and able to run small programs on OSX 10.8.  Be warned however
>   that it still asserts with bigger apps, and 32 bit programs are not
>   checked properly at all (most errors are missed by Memcheck).

Ok, that's fine.  So Valgrind should work, if temperamentally, on 10.8.1.  So now my question:

I was able to get Valgrind to compile on 10.8.1 with little trouble, but I saw some weird results when I ran it on a couple small C programs.  To try and reduce the possible causes of the issue, I eventually wrote the following "program":

```
int main () {                                                               
    return 0;
}
```

Not very exciting, and little room for bugs, I'd say.  Then, I compiled and ran it through Valgrind:

```
gcc testC.c
valgrind ./a.out
```

Here's my output:

```
==45417== Command: ./a.out
==45417== 
==45417== WARNING: Support on MacOS 10.8 is experimental and mostly broken.
==45417== WARNING: Expect incorrect results, assertions and crashes.
==45417== WARNING: In particular, Memcheck on 32-bit programs will fail to
==45417== WARNING: detect any errors associated with heap-allocated data.
==45417== 
--45417-- ./a.out:
--45417-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
==45417== 
==45417== HEAP SUMMARY:
==45417==     in use at exit: 58,576 bytes in 363 blocks
==45417==   total heap usage: 514 allocs, 151 frees, 62,442 bytes allocated
==45417== 
==45417== LEAK SUMMARY:
==45417==    definitely lost: 8,624 bytes in 14 blocks
==45417==    indirectly lost: 1,168 bytes in 5 blocks
==45417==      possibly lost: 4,925 bytes in 68 blocks
==45417==    still reachable: 43,859 bytes in 276 blocks
==45417==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==45417== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==45417== 
==45417== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==45417== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I know that Valgrind is not ready for prime-time on 10.8.1.  Nonetheless, I would love to be  able to use it here – I only need to use it on small programs, and nothing is mission-critical about the results being spot-on.  But clearly, it is reporting a ton of leaks in a program that seems very unlikely to be leaking.  Thus:

**What should I do to fix this?**

---

Other info:

- Adding an intentionally leaked integer *does* increment the "definitely lost" count by the  appropriate 4 bytes.
- Similarly, intentionally leaking a call to malloc by not freeing the memory *does* increment the heap alloc count appropriately.
- Compiling with the `-g` flag and then running to Valgrind (to address the `dSYM directory is missing` error) does cause that error to disappear, but *does not* change the issue of tons of memory leaks being reported.

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: This is outdated. In 2017, Valgrind suppresses most false positives.

Comment: @FranklinYu Does it suppress most false positives on 10.8.1? If so, write an answer to that effect and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @ravron Sorry, no (or at least not that I know). I only tested in 10.11. I was trying to say this issue probably depends on version of OS X. But you may still want to try with latest Valgrind, because they [do suppress *several* (if not *most*) false positives on 10.8](https://github.com/liquid-mirror/valgrind/blob/VALGRIND_3_12_0/darwin12.supp). It used not to suppress any false positives, known from your log `suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`. So at least it's improved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It tells you right there:

> Expect incorrect results, assertions and crashes.

If you still want to run it, print detailed information about spurious leaks (`--leak-check=full`) and use it to [suppress](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) messages about them.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer.  I'll go ahead and do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Valgrind trunk seems to have improved to the point where it is usable now. I haven't see it crash yet, but do have lots of false positives, which can be dealt with using a suppression file.

Right now, my suppression file looks like this:

```
# OS X 10.8 isn't supported, has a bunch of 'leaks' in the loader
{
   osx_1080_loader_false_positive_1
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   fun:_ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE
   ...
}
{
   osx_1080_loader_false_positive_2
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   fun:_ZN16ImageLoaderMachO16doInitializationERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextE
   ...
}
{
   osx_1080_loader_false_positive_3
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   fun:map_images_nolock
   ...
}
{
   osx_1080_loader_false_positive_4
   Memcheck:Leak
   ...
   fun:_objc_fetch_pthread_data
   fun:_ZL27_fetchInitializingClassLista
   fun:_class_initialize
   fun:_class_initialize
   fun:_class_initialize
   fun:_class_initialize
   fun:prepareForMethodLookup
   fun:lookUpMethod
   fun:objc_msgSend
   fun:_libxpc_initializer
   fun:libSystem_initializer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also running valgrind from macports on mac osx 10.8. It runs without crashing but does produce some crazy results like the ones in this stackoverflow post, [Confusing output from Valgrind shows indirectly lost memory leaks but no definitely lost or possibly lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670130/confusing-output-from-valgrind-shows-indirectly-lost-memory-leaks-but-no-definit/22672976#22672976).