# C++ or Cython memory leakage?

Tags: c++, python, memory-leaks, valgrind, cython

I am working on a python extension module written in cython, that wraps a C++ class I have written.

**The crash**

I have a simple python code that imports this python module and process some data with it. Now, about 1 time out of 4, the program segfaults just before termination, after the calls to the module. This meaning as well that all the data is correctly processed. It segfaults like this:

```
/Users/axe/anaconda/bin/python.app: line 2: 73168 Segmentation fault: 11
```

debugging with gdb, running `gdb python` and then `run code.py`, I get

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00000001000894ae in PyObject_ClearWeakRefs ()
```

the output of `backtrace` is

```
#0  0x00000001000894ae in PyObject_ClearWeakRefs ()
#1  0x00000001010edae4 in array_dealloc ()
#2  0x000000010007503e in tupledealloc ()
#3  0x00000001000559b7 in insertdict_by_entry ()
#4  0x0000000100059177 in PyDict_SetItem ()
#5  0x000000010005d286 in _PyModule_Clear ()
#6  0x00000001000df8cd in PyImport_Cleanup ()
#7  0x00000001000f0027 in Py_Finalize ()
#8  0x0000000100107e1b in Py_Main ()
#9  0x0000000100000f54 in start ()
```

So the segfault happens outside of my python code. I mention that the problem persists if I run the code from within ipython, or change interpreter/ipython to the one from the Enthought distribution, or if I downgrade Cython from 1.9.1 to 1.6.

**Memory leakage in C++ (?)**

Since this could look like a memory leak (please let me know if there are other possible explanations) in the C++ code, I ran Valgrind on some C++ test code of the C++ class, but it didn’t find any problems. (I am not 100% sure it is free of problems, because I am on OSX Mountain Lion, and despite having used the latest trunk version of Valgrind, it is known to have problems. I am using a OSX10.8 suppression file, with the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452541/valgrind-reports-leaked-memory-on-os-x-10-8-1) as a start). Anyway, the C++ class doesn’t use new/delete/malloc/free, so it SHOULD be fine.

**Memory leakage in Cython (?)**

I tried running valgrind on the python code that crashes. I have added a python suppression [file](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/valgrind-python.supp) in addition to the OSX suppression file mentioned above. Valgrind generates a lot of output and then crashes. In the output there isn’t any reference to my source codes. This is the incriminated cython code:

```
def split_props(np.ndarray[fptype, ndim=1, mode="c"] x,
                   np.ndarray[fptype, ndim=1, mode="c"] y,
                   np.ndarray[fptype, ndim=1, mode="c"] ylines):

cdef np.ndarray[fptype, ndim = 1, mode = "c"] areas = np.zeros((ylines.shape[0] + 1), dtype=np.float64, order="c")
cdef np.ndarray[fptype, ndim = 1, mode = "c"] static_moments_x = np.zeros((ylines.shape[0] + 1), dtype=np.float64, order="c")
cdef np.ndarray[fptype, ndim = 1, mode = "c"] inertia_moments_xx = np.zeros((ylines.shape[0] + 1), dtype=np.float64, order="c")

cdef SplitPolygon * SPINSTANCE = new SplitPolygon(100, 100)

SPINSTANCE.split_props(& x[0],  # = <fptype *> x.data
                         & y[0],
                         x.shape[0],
                         & ylines[0],
                         ylines.shape[0],
                         & areas[0],
                         & static_moments_x[0],
                         & inertia_moments_xx[0]
                         )
del SPINSTANCE
return areas, static_moments_x, inertia_moments_xx
```

Above, the C++ class is SplitPolygon. In the python code, I import from the cython module only the function `split_props` above, so the memory leak must be in this part of the code or in the C++ code. Moreover, the functionality of the python code is the same of the C++ test code.

I report below also another part of the module, that is very similar, but does NOT cause any memory leakage

```
def SplitCirc(np.ndarray[fptype, ndim=1, mode="c"] ycenters,
               np.ndarray[fptype, ndim=1, mode="c"] radii,
               np.ndarray[fptype, ndim=1, mode="c"] ylines):

cdef np.ndarray[fptype, ndim = 1, mode = "c"] areas = np.zeros((len(ylines) + 1), dtype=np.float64, order="c")
cdef np.ndarray[fptype, ndim = 1, mode = "c"] static_moments_x = np.zeros((len(ylines) + 1), dtype=np.float64, order="c")
cdef np.ndarray[fptype, ndim = 1, mode = "c"] inertia_moments_xx = np.zeros((len(ylines) + 1), dtype=np.float64, order="c")

split_circles(& ycenters[0], & radii[0], len(ycenters),
              & ylines[0], len(ylines),
              & areas[0], & static_moments_x[0], & inertia_moments_xx[0])
return areas, static_moments_x, inertia_moments_xx
```

Now, I am really stuck at this point. Does the cython code look good to you? Is there any test case I can code to check that the C++ class SplitPolygon is really leak-free? Can the crash happen for some other reasons?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a memory leak at all! It rather sounds as if the destructor of something is depending on something which just got destructed and depending on the order things get destroyed it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: A memory leak wouldn't cause a crash; it'd just waste more and more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. It was not a memory leak, as you pointed out.

The problem was in the data passed in the arrays `x,y,ylines`, that was wrong, because it didn't respect the specifications of the class `SplitPol()`.

This lead `SplitPols.split_props()` to undefined behaviour, that in this case was to write outside the boundaries of the 3 arrays passed by address in the call to `SPINSTANCE.split_props()`.

The three arrays were allocated by numpy with the 3 calls to `zeros()`. The corrupted memory was in their vicinity, and from run to run it could belong to a critical Python object, causing the segfault, or not, giving the appearance that everything was alright.

It didn’t help that the `SplitPols.split_props()` code was returning the correct data, apart for screwing the memory.