# Confusing output from Valgrind shows indirectly lost memory leaks but no definitely lost or possibly lost

Tags: c++, macos, valgrind

I am running valgrind on the macos x 10.8. Valgrind says on startup

```
"==11312== WARNING: Support on MacOS 10.8 is experimental and mostly broken.
==11312== WARNING: Expect incorrect results, assertions and crashes.
==11312== WARNING: In particular, Memcheck on 32-bit programs will fail to
==11312== WARNING: detect any errors associated with heap-allocated data."
```

Valgrind is giving this leak summary:

```
"LEAK SUMMARY:
==11312==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11312==    indirectly lost: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==11312==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11312==    still reachable: 45,857 bytes in 270 blocks
==11312==         suppressed: 16,805 bytes in 87 blocks"
```

According to valgrinds faq, http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost, "indirectly lost" means your program is leaking memory in a pointer-based structure. (E.g. if the root node of a binary tree is "definitely lost", all the children will be "indirectly lost".) If you fix the "definitely lost" leaks, the "indirectly lost" leaks should go away.

I dont have any definitely lost leaks or even possibly lost leaks to fix. What am I supposed to fix? Could this report be a bug due to the experimental nature of valgrind in 10.8?

I believe i am compiling this as a 64 bit program since the compiler is a 64 bit compiler.

Comment: I don't know how this works, but: Could it be something referenced from those suppressed leaks?

Comment: I am not sure its possible. I dont know enough about valgrind and how it works in Mac.                                                I am trying to test the software on linux right now to test the comment from presius but the software behavior is completely different on linux than in macos x. Apparently I have to rebug the program. The good news is according to valgrind on linux there are no leaks just 8 errors.

Comment: The errors show the code compiled on linux is skipping over functions so if the code should be f1->f2->f3. f2 is being skipped entirely. I got to love debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel weird answering my own question.

Yes the report by valgrind on mac is incorrect. According to valgrind on linux all heap blocks were freed so no leaks are possible.

I really hope valgrind fixes the issues with mac since I mainly am developing on mac now.

Comment: Heads up: they did :-)

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind has been [updated](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html). Use (if you use homebrew):

```
brew unlink valgrind
brew install valgrind
```

And, lo and behold:

```
==23998== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23998==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23998==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23998==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23998==    still reachable: 76,800 bytes in 2 blocks
==23998==         suppressed: 58,420 bytes in 359 blocks
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same _(no indirectly lost)_ results as of `Valgrind 3.11.0` on Mac OS X 10.8.x.

Comment: Thats awesome news. Unfortunately I have started to migrate away from developing on Macs.